# Append dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I have two dataframes in pandas
(copy from Spyder Variable Explorer)

df1

```
index   0    1    2    3    4    5   6
0       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light
1       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light
2       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light
3       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light
```

df2

```
index   0       1      2    3   4   5   6
0       DCos  -0.25  -0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
1       DCos  -0.25   0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
2       DCos   0.25  -0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
3       DCos   0.25   0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
```

I would like to append dataframe 2 to dataframe 1, to have

```
index   0    1    2    3    4    5   6      7       8     9    10   11  12  13                                         
0       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light  DCos  -0.25  -0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
1       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light  DCos  -0.25   0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
2       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light  DCos   0.25  -0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
3       Loc 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.25 0.0  light  DCos   0.25   0.2  0.9  nan nan nan
```

I have tried

```
df1.join.(df2)
```

but df1 was not changed. I know there is an append function described in the documentation, but in only appends rows. Is there a way to append columns ?

Comment: you want `pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I think he wants left-right merge on index, i.e. `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: @EdChum thanks that is what I wanted.

Comment: @Sam I wanted the indices to be as above, your code produces dataframe with 0_x ... and 0_y ... column indices for df1 and df2, but that was not my intention.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I do not have 50 rep points to comment. So this answer is just a comment as [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) has given the correct answer.

You should take a look at the documentation of the various types of concat, merge and join [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects).

If your trying to concatenate the two dataframes using the index, you simply need:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

This will place the second dataframe(df2) next to the first one(df1) where the indexes match.

If you want to concatenate without being index-sensitive, try

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```